# distanceFromLocation returns huge value without moving the tiniest bit

Tags: ios, core-location

I'm trying to call a function in case the distance traveled since last checked is > 30 m. Based on the Class description of CLLocationDistance the value returned is in m.

I use this code:

```
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
if (!startingLocation)
    startingLocation = locationManager.location;
//   NSLog(@"Latitude:%f Longitude:%f", startingLocation.coordinate.latitude, startingLocation.coordinate.longitude);

    updatedLocation = locationManager.location;
CLLocationDistance distance = [updatedLocation distanceFromLocation:startingLocation];
if (distance > 30) {
    NSLog(@"%f",distance);
    NSLog(@"Latitude:%f Longitude:%f", updatedLocation.coordinate.latitude, updatedLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    [self stop];
```

The console output with NSLog returns 7946754.993111, and I did not even touch the phone.
Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that because you are calling `startUpdatingLocation` then getting that location then immediately asking for an update that the location is still trying to figure out exactly where it is, hence the big movement.

Try calling `startUpdatingLocation` from another method then implement the delegate method from `CLLocationManager` `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation` to get the movement.

Answer (score 2):

8000 km between two points?  I'll bet the first point is 0, 0 and you're about 8000 km from there, right?

In any case be sure to only use valid locations by checking to make sure the horizontalAccuracy is >=0 before using the location coordinates.  Invalid locations have a negative horizontalAccuracy.

Also, you should probably discard any cached locations by checking the age of the location data and don't use it if it is more than a few seconds old.

See the [sample code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637356/154803) that does these checks.

Another thing to watch out for is that you can get locations that show false motion due to changes in accuracy.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3098788/154803) for details.